# R packages for supervised learning that use multithreaded BLAS

Tags: r, parallel-processing

What are some R packages for supervised learning that take advantage of multithreaded BLAS to do parallel computations (e.g., matrix multiplication)?  If R is compiled with a multithreaded BLAS implementation (e.g., ATLAS, GotoBlas2), are compiled R packages automatically linked to the same BLAS library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes -- BLAS a plugin standard, and you improve your run-time by going from "reference blas" (package refblas) to "automatically tuned linear algebra blas" (package atlas) and the multithreaded versions MKL (commercial), GotoBlas (now defunct) or OpenBLAS.

I have a package `gcbd` which provides a comparison framework, and a [draft vignette illustrating it](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gcbd/vignettes/gcbd.pdf).

(And Eigen / RcppEigen are different as Eigen does *by its own choice* bypass the BLAS interface for many / most operations.)

Comment: Thank you -- I get similar benchmarks as in the gcbd vignette. However, I do not see performance speed up for various regression packages (e.g., glmnet) that are based on matrix multiplication. Since such code is often compiled within R from C or Fortran, I would expect the compiled libraries to use the same multithreaded BLAS, but I see only single threaded performance.  Is there a way to force compiled R packages to use multithreaded BLAS?

Comment: They will use whatever BLAS you currently use with R.  But remember that the actual linear algebra bit may just be a very small part of the overall computation.

Comment: Agreed, but matrix multiplication with a large regression data set is typically a large part of an iterative fitting algorithm.  Which should tap multiple cores, whereas only a single core is active throughout the overall computation.  It may be a problem specific to the code in the particular packages I am using.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  You will only know if you profile the (and how to profile is discussed in "Writing R Extensions").